# spring boot elasticsearch java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: INDEX_CONTENT_TYPE error

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, elasticsearch

java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: INDEX_CONTENT_TYPE error

Elasticsearch Version : 7.16.2

```java
    // elasticsearch
    implementation 'org.springframework.data:spring-data-elasticsearch:4.3.0'
    implementation 'org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch:7.16.2'
    implementation 'org.elasticsearch.client:elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client:7.16.2'

    // jackson-core
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.13.1'
```

```java
public <T> void bulk(String indexName, List<T> documents, Class<T> tClass) {
        elasticsearchIndex.setIndexName(indexName);
        List<IndexQuery> queries = new ArrayList<>();
        for (T document : documents) {
            IndexQuery query = new IndexQueryBuilder()
                    .withObject(document)
                    .build();
            queries.add(query);
        }
        IndexOperations indexOps = elasticsearchTemplate.indexOps(tClass);
        if (!indexOps.exists()) {
            indexOps.create();
            indexOps.putMapping(indexOps.createMapping());
        }
        elasticsearchTemplate.bulkIndex(queries, tClass); // error
    }
```

```java
@Getter @Setter @ToString
@Document(indexName = "#{@elasticsearchIndex.getIndexName()}")
```

java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: INDEX_CONTENT_TYPE

Answer (score 1):

I experienced this same issue. I resolved it by downgrading Elastic Search and dependencies from `7.16` to `7.15`.

The current [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/current/reference/html/#preface.requirements) shows that `7.15.2` is the highest version currently support (or tested for release).

Comment: Instead of downgrading Elastic version, is there any other way to fix this error? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem you faced has been fixed in version 4.4.0 which supports elasticsearch 7.17.3.

Check https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/current/reference/html/#new-features.4-4-0

> 1.1. New in Spring Data Elasticsearch 4.4
>
> - ...
> - Upgrade to Elasticsearch 7.17.3.